# how to deploy java project with jenkins

Tags: java, ant, jenkins

I use jenkins to test my java project and it is successful, but I don't know how to deploy my project to tomcat with ant, how to do?

Comment: I assume you are using ant to build your project?

Comment: I use ant to build my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add following code to build.xml:

```
 <target name="dist" description="Unpack the file to war file" depends="compile">
   <war basedir="${dir.webRoot}" warfile="${webapp.deployPath}/${project.distname}.war"
                                     webxml="${dir.webRoot}/WEB-INF/web.xml">
    <exclude name="WEB-INF/web.xml"/>
    <exclude name="WEB-INF/lib/junit-4.6.jar"/>
   </war>
</target>
```

Answer (score 2):

Now, you need [Deploy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin).

This plugin takes a war/ear file and deploys that to a running remote application server at the end of a build. The implementation is based on Cargo. The list of currently supported containers include:

```
Tomcat 4.x/5.x/6.x/7.x
JBoss 3.x/4.x
Glassfish 2.x/3.x
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several defined ant tasks that you can download and incorporate into your flow to do exactly this. [Ant](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/AntDeploy) has a summary of the steps you would use to configure this.

Incorporate that into you build.xml and setup the steps in a separate deploy job and you should be good to go.

The steps for the above are for Tomcat 5.5 but they aren't dissimilar to what you would use for Tomcat 7. Also, simply doing a copy of the war file to the webapps dir in Tomcat will cause it to deploy if it is scanning for new wars automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Just add some code in build.xml

```
<target name="dist" description="Unpack the file to war file" depends="compile">
   <war basedir="${dir.webRoot}" warfile="${webapp.deployPath}/${project.distname}.war"
                                     webxml="${dir.webRoot}/WEB-INF/web.xml">
    <exclude name="WEB-INF/web.xml"/>
    <exclude name="WEB-INF/lib/junit-4.6.jar"/>
   </war>
</target>
```